# Is NameId required? saml2 itfoxtec-identity-saml2

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I'm setting up a saml2 authorization, and is using itfoxtec libary.
But from the idp i only get one attribute value and no NameId.
In my assertionConsumerService i get a ArgumentNullException on nameId.
They say that nameId is optional, so therefore they only send the attribute value.

So can you use itfoxtec without nameid or is it requred?

Adding stacktrace

Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2SecurityTokenReadException: IDX13102: Exception thrown while reading 'NameIDType' for Saml2SecurityToken. Inner exception: 'System.ArgumentNullException: IDX10000: The parameter 'value' cannot be a 'null' or an empty object. (Parameter 'value')
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2NameIdentifier.set_Value(String value)
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2Serializer.ReadNameIdType(XmlDictionaryReader reader)'.
---> System.ArgumentNullException: IDX10000: The parameter 'value' cannot be a 'null' or an empty object. (Parameter 'value')
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2NameIdentifier.set_Value(String value)
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2Serializer.ReadNameIdType(XmlDictionaryReader reader)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2Serializer.ReadNameIdType(XmlDictionaryReader reader)
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2Serializer.ReadNameId(XmlDictionaryReader reader)
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2Serializer.ReadNameIdentifier(XmlDictionaryReader reader, String parentElement)
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2Serializer.ReadSubject(XmlDictionaryReader reader)
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2Serializer.ReadAssertion(XmlReader reader)
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2SecurityTokenHandler.ReadSaml2Token(XmlReader reader)
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2SecurityTokenHandler.ReadSaml2Token(String token)
at ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Saml2AuthnResponse.ReadSecurityToken(String tokenString)
at ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Saml2AuthnResponse.Read(String xml, Boolean validateXmlSignature, Boolean detectReplayedTokens)
at ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Saml2PostBinding.Read(HttpRequest request, Saml2Request saml2RequestResponse, String messageName, Boolean validateXmlSignature, Boolean detectReplayedTokens)
at ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Saml2Binding`1.ReadSamlResponse(HttpRequest request, Saml2Response saml2Response)
at ...Controllers.AuthorizationsController.AssertionConsumerService() in ...Areas\Client\Controllers\AuthorizationsController.cs:line 95

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ITfoxtec Identity SAML2 component without a `NameID`, but then you are not able to do logout or single logout. `NameID` is optional in login but not in logout and single logout.

Where are you experiencing a `ArgumentNullException`?

**UPDATE**

I have [added support](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/commit/6a834aef79e208b39cc2f156982b50b114bb1849) for issuing SAML 2.0 tokens without a `NameID` and testet that the component accept tokens without `NameID`. You should not experience an error. Are you using the latest version 2.8.2?

Comment: Ok. I'm getting the error in my assertionConsumerService when it runs this code binding.ReadSamlResponse(GenericHttpRequest, saml2AuthnResponse)

Comment: The error message is {"message":"IDX13102: Exception thrown while reading 'NameIDType' for Saml2SecurityToken. Inner exception: 'System.ArgumentNullException: IDX10000: The parameter 'value' cannot be a 'null' or an empty object. (Parameter 'value')\r\n at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2NameIdentifier.set_Value(String value)\r\n at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2Serializer.ReadNameIdType(XmlDictionaryReader reader)'.","code":"500","arguments":"null"}

Comment: Code example https://pastebin.com/jW8S1U9b

Comment: I'm not able to fint the problem. Please add the full stack trace as a update to the original questions.

Comment: Have added stack trace

Comment: I have version 4.8.0, but i can test to upgrade

Comment: I get the same error in version 4.8.2

Comment: What is the .NET version?

Comment: .NET core 3.1 But i managed to persuade the people who config the idp. So they send the value as NameID now. But thanks for the help

Comment: Thank you for the information and great to hear you got it to work.